# Is there a way to start a branch (based on a label) in the root of a team project?

Tags: tfs, branch

I'm in the following situation with TFS 2010:

- I have a team project (with 2 sub-folders of source code).
- The team project has no branches but has been labelled in the past.
- I need to create a branch in the root of the team project, based on a specific (and historic) label.

I have tried this method (all in Source Control Explorer):

1. Right-click team project and go to Branch...
2. Change Target to `$/MyTeamProject/NewBranchName`
3. Choose appropriate label.
4. Uncheck "Convert source and target folders to branches".

When I click OK I receive this error:

> The target item `$/MyTeamProject/NewBranchName` cannot be under the
>   source item `$/MyTeamProject`.

Any ideas?

PS. I **was** able to branch the label into a different team project, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the item `$/MyTeamProject` is included in your label, then TFS can't create a branch under that path.

So edit the label and remove the `$/MyTeamProject` path and try again.

**EDIT :**

You can only remove a folder using the [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2010).

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate this on Monday.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to remove the `$/MyTeamProject` path. If I try deleting the folder it removes all the content beneath it. (As you'd expect).

Comment: No, I mean remove the folder from the label. First find the label, then edit it, it will list all the files/folders that are part of it (with their version), find the reference to the folder and remove it. DO NOT remove the folder from the source control.

Comment: When I go to "Edit label" I see a screen with a folder structure on the left and files/folders on the right. I can't see a way of removing the root folder path by itself. I understand what you're saying but is it definitely possible in my version of TFS (2010)?

Comment: oh, sorry, I can't test right now because I don't have VS10. Download the TFS Sidekicks http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ you can edit items of a label.

Comment: I just did the test with the TFS Sidekicks and I could remove only the folder and still keep the files inside, so you should be able to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too - it won't let you turn the label into a branch. I think it's because it has no root folder to use as the branch root.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to create a branch under the root of the branch you are branching from.  That is, by right-clicking on the **team project** and selecting branch, you cannot create a branch under that team project.

Instead, try the branch operation from the folders.  That will allow you to place them under the team project.  If you want them to have a single common root, you will likely need to branch them separately into a subfolder under the team project.